# Yii select multiplication of two columns in yii using createCommand

Tags: select, yii

How to write following select query using `yii` **createCommand**. this runs perfect in phpmyadmin?

```
SELECT total_units, nav, total_units * nav as total 
FROM user_nav_stats 
where total_units !=0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to run it as SQL you can do this

```
$connection->createCommand('SELECT total_units, nav, total_units * nav as total FROM user_nav_stats where total_units !=0')->queryAll();
```

But i would use the Querybuilder. It's something like this. [More can be found here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html)

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['total_units', 'nav', 'total_units * nav as total'])
    ->from('user_nav_stats')
    ->where(['!=','total_units',0])
    ->all();
```